# How to explain this observation in Franck-Hertz experiment?

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-current, atomic-physics

We did the [Franck-Hertz experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Hertz_experiment) in our physics lab. The setup was like this

[image]

We fixed the value of $V_{G_{1}K}$ and varied the values of $V_{G_{2}K}$ and got the curve for the electron current vs the potential $V_{G_{2}K}$ . Then we changed the value of $V_{G_{1}K}$ to a higher value and got the similar curve but what we observed was that the peak values of the current decreased and it further decreased with increasing value of  $V_{G_{1}K}$.

I have no reason why this happened, neither our instructor have any answer.

So can someone explain this to me ?

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a fixed amplitude of $I_p$, increasing $V_{G_1K}$ requires larger $V_{G_2K}$ to maintain the same acceleration voltage (voltage difference between G1 and G2). So in terms of $I_p$ plotted against $V_{G_2K}$, the curve will be moving to the left when you increase $V_{G_1K}$. Since the curve is climbing up while osccilating, you misinterpret the left-moving of the curve as a decrease in the peak value.